# Не возвращает фрагмент при поиске по тегу

Tags: java, android, activity, android-fragment, fragment-transaction

В класе активности инициализирую экземпляр фрагмента! Примерно все выглядит так:

```
public class HelloMoonActivity extends FragmentActivity {


        private final String TAG_FRAGMENT_AUDIO = "fragment_audio";
        private final String TAG_FRAGMENT_VIDEO = "fragment_video";

        private Button playAndPauseButton;
        private Button stopButton;
        private Button videoAndAudioButton;

        private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

        private HelloMoonFragment helloMoonFragment;
        private HelloMoonVideoFragment helloMoonVideoFragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_moon);
            videoAndAudioButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hello_moon_govideo_button);

            initWidget();

            if(savedInstanceState == null){
                initDefaultView();
            }



            videoAndAudioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    if (videoAndAudioButton.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Video")) {

                        HelloMoonVideoFragment fragment = (HelloMoonVideoFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_VIDEO);

                        if (fragment == null) {
                            videoAndAudioButton.setText(R.string.hello_moon_goaudio);
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_moon_conteiner, helloMoonVideoFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_VIDEO);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        }






                    } else if (videoAndAudioButton.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Audio")) {

                        HelloMoonFragment fragment = (HelloMoonFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_AUDIO);
                        if (fragment == null) {
                            videoAndAudioButton.setText(R.string.hello_moon_govideo);
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_moon_conteiner, helloMoonFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_AUDIO);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        }




                    }
                }

            });

        }

        private void initDefaultView(){
            helloMoonFragment = new HelloMoonFragment();
            helloMoonVideoFragment = new HelloMoonVideoFragment();

            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_moon_conteiner, helloMoonFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        private void initWidget(){
            playAndPauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hello_moon_play_button);
            stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hello_moon_stop_button);
            videoAndAudioButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hello_moon_govideo_button);
        }
    }
```

Вроде бы все правильно делаю **НО**  когда делаю:

```
HelloMoonVideoFragment fragment = (HelloMoonVideoFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_VIDEO);
```

fragment == null.

И даже после того как я повторно добавил фрагмент на активити , то есть:

```
HelloMoonFragment fragment = (HelloMoonFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_AUDIO);
if (fragment == null) {
videoAndAudioButton.setText(R.string.hello_moon_govideo);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_moon_conteiner, helloMoonFragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_AUDIO);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
fragment = (HelloMoonFragment) fragmentManager.findByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_AUDIO);
}
```

fragment все равно null.

**Что я делаю не так ?**

**Как решить эту ошибку ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед `fragmentTransaction.commit();` добавьте

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(name)
```

Comment: а name чего должно указываться ??

Comment: @Vitaliy нужный тег

Answer (score 1):

Зачем в `initDefaultView()` создаете фрагменте, которые нигде не используются? null у Вас скорей всего из-за того, что в этом же методе commit-ите `fragmentTransaction`